# Can Crashlytics send reports while an app is running in the background?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Our app is a location-based app which could crash while running in the background.
If the app crashes in the background, Crashlytics's report will be sent the next time the app becomes foreground.
However the app can be re-launched in the background by significant location changes.
Is there a way to send reports when the app awaken in the background before its user brings the app foreground?

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. There currently isn't a way within the SDK to force reports to be sent based on a trigger or SDK call.